# JQuery - Require a Form Field if Visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, powerapps

I'm using the Jquery code below for a webform in Power App Portals. The code hides the **BIL Category** drop-down field based on the choice selected in the **Type of Funding Request** drop-down field. This all works perfectly.

Now I simply want to require the **BIL Category** field if it is visible. How can I modify the code to achieve this?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#cr92d_typeoffundingrequest").change(onDisplaySectionChange);
     onDisplaySectionChange();
});

function onDisplaySectionChange() {
    var varFunding = $('#cr92d_typeoffundingrequest').find("option:selected").text();
    if (varFunding === "DWSRF") 
    
    {
    $('#cr92d_bilcategory').parent().parent().hide();
    }
    else{$('#cr92d_bilcategory').parent().parent().show();
}
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

```
    else
{
    $('#cr92d_bilcategory').parent().parent().show();
    $('#cr92d_bilcategory').prop('required', true);     
   $('#cr92d_bilcategory').closest(".control").prev().addClass("required");
    }
```

Try this.